# Why does an alertdialog with edittext refresh my listview?

Tags: listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, android-lifecycle

I am relatively new to Android programming / the Activity Lifecycle. I have an app with a listview that is being populated by an array list of custom objects. When that arraylist is created an Asynctask is called which pulls in information from an API and saves it into the arraylist. When the app starts the arraylist is being successfully populated into the listview with information from the API. Unfortunately, when I navigate back to the home screen then reenter the app my listview is empty. My empty listview shows up populated again when I lock and unlock the device or when I press a button on the screen that brings up an alert dialog though.

Currently, I am relying on a refresh button that calls the alert dialog which refreshes the listview. I would like to eliminate the need for this refresh button so the app automatically refreshes. Could you help me understand why the code below refreshes results? I have tried a number of different methods to fix this issue in oncreate and onrestart to no success so far.

```
public void refreshResults(final View view) {
    // Creating alert Dialog with one Button
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setView(input);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Refreshing results");

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
          }
        });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
Project
|
|-AdjustInventory
|-AdjustInventoryLogin
|-Administrator Activity
|-CustomItemsAdapter
|-FetchInventory
|-FetchInventoryLogin
|-Item
|-MainActivity
```

The asynctask to populate the arraylist is called outside of a function in the first few lines of the MainActivity via Item.getitems. The adapter is being set via an Asynctask Load in onPostExecute that includes a processdialog. The Load Asynctask is being called in onResume. I've tried setting the adapter in onCreate, onRestoreInstanceState, onStart, and onResume as well and had the same problem as before I used a Load Asynctask to set the adapter.

Comment: Where specifically are you calling the Asynctask to populate the array and when are you setting the adapter to the listview?

Comment: Thanks @diedu I've edited the post to answer your questions.